# Remove an item from a column type of array in Parse (iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have table name "Events". In that table I have a column of type array of string. I'm struggling with how I can delete only one element from that column. Consider the image below, I want to delete all the occurrences of "iYYeR2a2rU" from the "usersIncluded" column, without deleting the rows.
I've used the `removeObject:(id) forKey:(NSString *)` and it didn't work.

[image]

This is how I'm trying to achieve it:

```
  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Events"];
    NSArray *eventObjects = [query findObjects];
    [query whereKey:@"usersIncluded" equalTo:[self.uniqeFriendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        for (int i = 0; i<objects.count; i++) {
            PFObject *event = [eventObjects objectAtIndex:i];
            [event removeObject:[self.uniqeFriendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"usersIncluded"];
        }
    }];
}
```

The `self.uniqeFriendList` is a mutable array containing the ids that I want to delete from the 'usersIncluded' column.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have a `PFObject` subclass in your code for `Event`?

Comment: @JamesFrost No I don't have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're using the right method (`removeObject:forKey:` should do exactly what you want) but I think you're working with objects from the wrong array. You're performing your query twice, and within the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` you're working with the array from the first time you called it... Try this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Events"];
[query whereKey:@"usersIncluded" equalTo:[self.uniqeFriendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
    for (int i = 0; i <objects.count; i++) {
        PFObject *event = [objects objectAtIndex:i];    // note using 'objects', not 'eventObjects'
        [event removeObject:[self.uniqeFriendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"usersIncluded"];
    }

    [PFObject saveAll:objects];
}];
```

}